# Stable state and don't care

Tags: logic-gates, flipflop, latch, stable

I have a `latch` but I can't understand what are the meaning of `Un/Stable state` and `"don't care"`.

[image: latch]

I found a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) about the definition of the state, but I didn't understand that fluently.

I try to understand these questions:
**Statemanet A:** while `Q2=1`, `Q1=0` we get stable state.
but why?

**Statemanet B:** while `A=1`, `B=0` we get "don't care" situation.
but why?

And then I understand that i don't really understand what exactly the meaning.

I made a truth table:

[image: Truth table]

But still, im not sure I understand the conclusion

Comment: these words don't mean much without *context*, which is what you're sadly not giving...

Comment: I edited my question. hope I added some context

Comment: notice that the question asks about "stable **state**", not "stable **latch**", and that's the important difference here (so I changed you question's title)

Comment: Have you (tried to) make a **truth table** of this circuit? That's a table which shows the values of Q1 and Q2 depending on the values of A and B. Note that not for all states it will be straightforward to determine what Q1 and Q2 are, then Q1 and Q2 might depend on their previous value.

Comment: How can I make a truth table if I don't know the q1, q2 in the "or" gate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK. Thanks

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I added my truth table to the question... but what can I conclude from that about the stable and unstable and don't care

Comment: I do understand how latch works. I'm trying to study to an exam... These are questions from older exams.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Why its wrong. I tried again, with same result. I fill 3 rows as you see.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought there was another NOT gate at the B input. I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say that you have a stable state just because Q2=1 and Q1=0...you must also specify that values of the inputs. You need to **assume** that Q2 and Q1 have a particular value and then consider specific values of the inputs. If you propagate the assumed Q2 and Q1 as well as the specified input values and determine that the actual value of Q2 and Q1 is the same as your assumed value, **then** you have identified a stable state.

A=1 and B=0 is **not** a "don't care" input condition. You can say that you have a "don't care" input condition only if the final values of Q2 and Q1 **do not** depend on the previous values of Q2 and Q1. In other words, the output state is determined entirely by the inputs and you don't care about the previous output state. For the circuit you provided, all of the input conditions except A=1 and B=0 are don't care conditions.

For the A=1 and B=0 input case you have to make an assumption about the states of Q1 and Q2, then determine if that is a **stable** state. Do this for the situations where the latch is storing a logical 1 and for when it is storing a logical 0 (it's not clear how Q1 and Q2 relate to the stored state of your circuit). If you find that the stored state is always stable for a particular set of input values then you have found the **HOLD** input condition...the input condition that holds the previously stored value in the latch.